# рекурсия Pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Есть задача:

> Составить рекурсивную программу для нахождения n-й итерации (n=0, 1,
> 2,…) функции F(x) в точке a. Программа должна вычислять значение
> выражения вида F(F(F…F(a)…)) при n-кратном использовании операции F.

Мой код. Укажите в чем моя ошибка?

```
var
  f, a, n: integer;

function iter(a, n: integer): integer;
begin
  if n <= 0 then iter := 0
  else begin
    f := sqr(a) + a;
    iter := f;
    iter(a, n - 1);
  end;
end;

begin
  writeln('');readln(a);
  writeln('');readln(n);
  writeln(iter(a, n));
end.
```

Comment: Значение, полученное при рекурсивном вызове, ничему не присваивается и соответственно не используется.

Comment: @MBo Да и `iter := 0` тоже.

Comment: @Igor Ну это-то result при n=0, наверх отдаётся, только не используется на высшем уровне

Comment: @MBo Если это значение будет использоваться на высшем уровне, могу предсказать, какой будет ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
function iter(a, n: integer): integer;
begin
  if n > 1 then 
  begin
    a := iter(a, n - 1);
  end;
  iter := sqr(a) + a;
end;
```