# Ошибка : Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

Необходима написать программу ввода Автомобиля и его вывода с использованием ООП.
Возникает ошибка Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта  при начале ввода первого атрибута Авто.

```
using System;
```

namespace лб2
{

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int k;
        Console.WriteLine("Введите колличество легковых авто:");
        k = Console.Read();
        Console.Clear();


            for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            {
                Passengercar[] myCar = new Passengercar[k];
                Console.WriteLine("Введите марку " + i + "-го легкового авто");
                myCar[i].marka = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите модель " + i + "-го легкового авто");
                myCar[i].model = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите страну производителя " + i + "-го легкового авто");
                myCar[i].countryrelease = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите цвет производителя " + i + "-го легкового авто");
                myCar[i].color = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите цену авто " + i + "-го легкового авто");
                myCar[i].price = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите радиус колёс " + i + "-го легкового авто");
                myCar[i].rwheels = Console.ReadLine();
            }


        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
        {
            Passengercar[] myCar = new Passengercar[k];
            myCar[i].show_pass_car(k);
        }



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

 class Auto
{
    public string marka;
    public string model;
    public string countryrelease;
    public string color;
    public string price;
}

class Passengercar : Auto
{
    public string rwheels;
    public void show_pass_car(int k)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Авто 1: " + marka+"  " + model + "  " + countryrelease + "  " + color + "  " + price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950184/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-pascal

Comment: Первоначально думаю классы ```Auto``` и ```Passengercar ``` попробуй сделать ```public```, а потом дальше будем думать

Answer (score 0):

```
Passengercar[] myCar = new Passengercar[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
  //Passengercar[] myCar = new Passengercar[k];
  myCar[i] = new Passengercar();
  ...
}

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
   myCar[i].show_pass_car(k);
}
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев Все изменилось. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код и не перекомпилировали программу.

Comment: ок, а почему цикл бесконечный стал не подскажешь?

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев Какой цикл бесконечный?

Comment: ну я вначале ввожу столько то машин, но он тупо продолжается, сам цикл бесконечный

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев В коде, который Вы привели, нет бесконечных циклов. Вы запускаете какой-то другой код.